# Bootstrap : Show modal window on image click in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have to open image modal window on image click in a loop . this is what i am doing that does not produce required results . Kindly check if logic is correct or something is wrong with it

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<5;$i++):?>
        <a id = "<?=$i?>" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Molf.png?s=48&g=1" alt="">  </a>


<div class="modal fade" id="<?=$i?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;</button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Some content 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<?=$i?>").click(function () {
            $('#<?=$i?>').modal('show'); 
        });
    }); 

</script>
<?php endfor;?>
```

a black layer comes on top of it but modal does not show up see attached image 
[image]

Comment: What is the current result and what is the expected result?

Comment: do you have a plunkr to reproduce?

Comment: see the image attached to see the result

Comment: You cannot repeat your ids for multiple elements. each element should have an unique id

Comment: what should be the solution please help

Comment: This is not a good idea to write multiple click function in loop .You just have to use class name and write one function in which id has been passed on onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , Hope it will work

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i<5;$i++):?>
    <a id = "<?=$i?>" class="aclick" href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Molf.png?s=48&g=1" alt="">  </a>


    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_<?=$i?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        &times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Some content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor;?>
```

SCRIPT :-

```
$(".aclick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $('#modal_'+id).modal('show');
    });
```